# How to get full extended UserAgent from PHP in IE9

Tags: php, internet-explorer-9, user-agent

in IE9 The command `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` in php returns only the **short** UA string

and in JavaScript I can get the extended UserAgent with `navigator.userAgent` property

Is there a way to get the full **extended** UserAgent in PHP from IE9?

the purpose is to get the strings i have put in the regitry: 
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\User Agent\Post Platform
the extended UserAgent contain the strings from regitry.

[Introducing IE9’s User Agent String](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/23/introducing-ie9-s-user-agent-string.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The difference between JavaScript and PHP implementations of `getuserAgent()` function is - JavaScript communicates with browser itself while PHP knowns only data sent earlier by browser to server.

There is function `get_browser()` in PHP (since PHP 4) which can give you most information from data available to server: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.get-browser.php. Beware that this function relies on *browscap.ini* which is not bundled in PHP and should be updated and installed manually.

Anyway there are no **extended** information about user's browser available on server side.

Comment: This *could* work, but relies on browsercap.ini being configured, and that it's up-to-date

Comment: @Brian: That's what in documentation said, but I should mention it on my reply, right. Anyway the result of `get_broswer()` is based on HTTP_USER_AGENT header, so no *extended* data is available on server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it gets sent with the headers, only way would be to access

```
navigator.userAgent
```

with javascript and push it to your server with AJAX.

**EDIT**

Or, use PHP's getallheaders() function to check all the headers sent with a request.

Answer (score 0):

In the link that you posted by yourself, [Introducing IE9's User Agent String](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/23/introducing-ie9-s-user-agent-string.aspx), it says:

> IE9 will send the short UA string by default

The server doesn't recieve the long User Agent String. The only solution I can think of, is to post with AJAX, but that really is safe. People can just turn of their javascript.